# Where does come this power loss?

Tags: transformer, electric-machine

Regarding the next problem [image]

why is asumed that there was a power loss of 928 W>?

Comment: Because P_in - P_out = 928? There was a 928W difference between the input and output power, so it was a loss.

Comment: Right, I didn’t picked the idea.

Comment: It is a loss of only 3.1%, which is not bad at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30,000 watts divided by the stated efficiency of 97% = an input power of 30,927.8 watts hence the loss is 927.8 watts.